# Poweredge R410 os installing

Tags: windows, operating-system

Im new here and i have no clue about servers.
I recently bought a poweredge R410 with 64gb ram 16 core 2Tb single SAS hd.
I downloaded windows server 2012 from microsoft and i failed to install it.
There is no clear way online to do so.
My goal is actually to install windows 7 on it in case my softwares didnt work on the server os.

Forgive me for my noob question but i really hope that i can find a clear answer.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Right now, your question lacks any helpful description. The good thing is, you can simply [edit] your question and include as much description as you like. Please take the time to explain what you are doing where you hit a problem. Please read [about] and [ask] before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded windows server 2012 from microsoft and i failed to
>   install it.

Some details about the failure would be helpful.

> There is no clear way online to do so.

You can use the LifeCycle Controller to install Windows Server 2012/2012R2.

AFAIK, Windows Server 2016 and 2019 aren't supported on the R410.

https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln129177/how-to-install-the-operating-system-on-a-dell-poweredge-server-os-deployment?lang=en#LCC